# Async Task not executing properly on calling from notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to call some activity from notification which contains AsyncTask. when I click on the notification it is opening a particular activity but not executing doInBackground of async. if I call directly that activity (not from notification) then async task works fine.

**here is my service class(calling notification from service)**

```
  package com.example.gajanand.simpletask;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;


import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MyService extends Service {

    List<UserListResponse> userListResponse;

    boolean datadownloded =false;


    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FetchFromApi();


            }
        });

        thread.start();


        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void sendNotification() {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "notify_001");
        Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecyclerViewActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, ii, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigText.bigText("Downloaded");
        bigText.setBigContentTitle("Download");
        bigText.setSummaryText("Status");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Your Title");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Your text");
        mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        mBuilder.setStyle(bigText).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notify_001",
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());



    }

    private void FetchFromApi() {


        (Api.getClient().getUsersList()).enqueue(new Callback<List<UserListResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<UserListResponse>> call, Response<List<UserListResponse>> response) {
                Log.d("Gajanand", response.body().get(0).getName());
                userListResponse = response.body();
//                setDataInRecyclerView();
                MyDb myDb=MyDb.getInstance(MyService.this);


                datadownloded= myDb.insertUserDetails(userListResponse);

                Log.d("Gajanand", "onResponse: "+datadownloded);

                if(datadownloded){
                    sendNotification();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<UserListResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                // if error occurs in network transaction then we can get the error in this method.
//                Toast.makeText(GetActivity.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        this.stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

**and this is my Recycleractivity which I want to call from notification.**

```
 public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);


        FetchData fetchData = new FetchData();

        fetchData.execute();
    }

    class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(RecyclerViewActivity.this);
        List<UserListResponse> userListResponse;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress.setMessage("Fetching data... ");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            super.onPostExecute(integer);

            Log.d("Gajanand", "onPostExecute: " + integer);

            progress.dismiss();

            for (UserListResponse userListResponse : userListResponse) {

                Log.d("Gajanand", "onPostExecute: " + userListResponse.getName());

            }


        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                MyDb myDb = MyDb.getInstance(RecyclerViewActivity.this);
                userListResponse = myDb.fetchAlldata();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Gajanand", "doInBackground: " + e.toString());

            }
            return 0;
        }


    }

}
```

**and here is my manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gajanand.simpletask">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity android:name=".RecyclerViewActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and I am starting Service from the main activity.

can anyone tell me? why from notification Async not working?

Comment: this is really bad code. Memory leaks, NPEs, sweet path. Also, it's missing the MyDB code. What kind of a boolean does `insertUserDetails` return, and when?

Comment: @f.khantsis how and where?

Comment: Also, I would check if `RecyclerViewActivity.onCreate` is called

Comment: @f.khantsis yes it is called ..because progress dialog is appearing but control is not entering in doInbackground